# jQuery clear textboxes and reset to default drop down menu values

Tags: jquery

On click want to clear all (**not reset**) input (clear also default textbox values). Need very short, simple code that uses as little as possible resources.

HTML form

```
<form id="form2" action='project_manager' method='post'>
<input type='text' name='project' value="default value" >
<select name='job_number'>
<option value='0'></option>
<option value='1'>job1</option>
</select>

<input type="button" id="clear_all" value="Clear all" />
</form>
```

jQuery

```
$('input[id="clear_all"]').click (function () {
$(':input').val('');

});
});
```

But this clears also value of button. Value of button must remain.

Changed to `$('form :input[type=text]').val("");`

How to reset drop down menu value?

Tried `$('form :select').val("");` and `$('form :select').selectedIndex = -1;`. Something incorrect...

Comment: On which button you want to reset the form?

Comment: what can't you use html reset button ?

Comment: @JanithChinthana If you mean `<input type="reset" id="clear_all" value="Clear all" />` then it resets to default values in text boxes. I need empty text boxes

Comment: I posted an answer which help you to clear every possible fields inside the form, it may help you if your form will grow with new fields such as checkboxes radio button file.. etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(':input').not(":button").val('');
```

reference **[not](http://api.jquery.com/not/)**

Comment: This seems the shortest solution

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
$('form select').val("");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `input type="reset"`:

```
<input type="reset" id="clear_all" value="Clear all" />
```

You don't need to write a line of code.

Comment: It resets default values in text boxes

Comment: @user2465936: it seems that this only works if your default value is empty string. That's just 1 suggestion. If your default value is empty string, you could use this. Usually, `clear` means reset to default value.

Answer (score 1):

this is code for clear all the fields inside the form.

```
$('#myform').find('input:text, input:password, input:file, select, textarea').val('');
$('#myform').find('input:radio, input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked').removeAttr('selected');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
document.getElementById('formId').reset();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(':input:not([type=button])').val('');
```

Comment: @Denomales - The OP said their code works as expected. The problem the were having was that the submit button's text was being overwritten. This selector omits the submit button.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $("#button_clear").click(function() { 
          document.getElementById('formId').reset(); 
    }); 
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Change button type to reset

```
 <input type="reset" id="clear_all" value="Clear all" />
```

No jquery needed the values will be cleared

Answer (score -1):

```
try this.
 $('select').val(" ");
```